# Dockerfile: ENTRYPOINT and CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I saw for example in the Dockerfile of the postgres image (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/Dockerfile) that at the end the startup of the container is defined like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

If I understand this right, the argument `postgres` is transferred into the `docker-entrypoint.sh` so `$1` in the script is replaced with `postgres` and the script will be executed.

Now my question is if I can define my own Dockerfile based on the postgres image (`FROM postgres`) but overwrite the `CMD` of the base Dockerfile and accomplish to first execute a command on startup and then execute the `docker-entrypoint.sh` with the `postgres` argument?

Something like this:

```
FROM postgres
...
CMD <my-command> && [“postgres”]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create you own `my-entrypoint.sh`

```
$ cat my-entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash

#do what you need here e.g. <my-command>

#next command will run postgres entrypoint will all params
docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

And your docker file will look as follows

```
FROM postgres

# your stuff

ENTRYPOINT ["my-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do such a thing

For the CMD command in a Dockerfile, you have 3 possible syntaxes

Extract from

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

`CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)
 CMD ["param1","param2"] (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
 CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)`

So you can use any, for doing what you want, the shell form (the last one) seems well suited

You can also launch a shell script that does all your stuff

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Or could you please give an example of the syntax what I want to accomplish

Comment: read also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile?rq=1

Comment: root execution of the PostgresSQL is not permitted

Comment: I guess you have not created a non privileged user, and so your Dockerfile does not have a `USER` directive. You should post your Dockerfile

Comment: But isn’t the postgres entrypoint script supposed to create this user (see https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh)

Comment: see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ extract `docker run -it --rm --user 1000:1000...` so it uses a nonprivileged user

Comment: So than how do I accomplish this?

Comment: does this form "CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)" is also parameters for ENTRYPOINT please ?